# How can I building flutter app for android?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dart, build

Im traing to build my app, but when I use this comands `flutter build appbundle` i catch this erro

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.                
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.                
> Keystore file not set for signing config release                      
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 54s                                                     
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                        55,7s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

How i can solve this ?

Comment: "Keystore file not set for signing config release" do you have all your credentials correctly to make a release build?

Answer (score 1):

- Create a keystore
- Reference the keystore from the app
- Configure
  signing in gradle

by following [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app) tutorial.